# Why fast-csv doesn't store the data in NodeJS ?

Tags: node.js, file, csv

Hello I just want to store a column of a CSV in node to manipulate the data in an array and I'm trying to read it and store it but it does'nt work whats happening ? here is my code

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream("Supliers.csv");

let csvStream = csv({headers: true})
.on("data", function(data){
     /*data.forEach(x => {
      console.log(x)
     })*/

     Final.push(data)
})
.on("end", function(){
     console.log(Final);//[THE COMPLETE DATA TOTALLY OK]
});

stream.pipe(csvStream);

console.log(Final)// []
```

I dont understand :( HELP

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code, I have added comments.

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream("Supliers.csv");

let csvStream = csv({headers: true}).on("data", function(data){
     // This is inside a function that gets slightly later, in the 
     // next tick of the event loop.  I.e. it's called after
     // the 'console.log(Final)' statement.
     Final.push(data)
})
.on("end", function(){
     // You can do your processing in this function
     console.log(Final);
});

stream.pipe(csvStream);

// This gets called before the '.on("data"...' function.
console.log(Final)

// To prove that this works (***but don't use this in your code***)
// the following should work too.
setTimeout(() => console.log(Final), 100);
```

I recommend some reading on the Node.js event loop: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: What can I do to store the data to use it in another function ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: That depends what you want to do with it.  You can put your necessary code in the `.on("end"...` function.  This is a good place to handle the data.

Comment: I'll Try @psiphi75 Thanks